# Service Worker slow response times for css

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

We have service worker written on top of sw-toolbox. Once the static resources are cached service worker is taking longer time  especially for downloading css resources (30 - 100ms)  where as for js resources the time is almost 0.

**CSS load times  :**

Load 1 : 35ms

Load 2 : 25ms

Load 3 : 101ms

Load 4 :  22ms

**Js load times :**

Load 1 : 0 ms

Load 2 : 0 ms

Load 3 : 0 ms

Load 4 : 0 ms

**Question** :

1.Why css load times are higher with service worker? Would be really helpful to us if someone can provide insight on this.

2.We use preload (async)  for loading css , with higher load times for css service worker is fetching css bit late ( after fetching js) due to which page content is getting displayed with out css at first and later with css ( i.e Flickering effect , content without css to content with css)

Comment: Please include a screenshot from your Chrome Dev Tools showing all these requests. It makes it easier to answer :) Also: I don't really understand your second question, could you improve it a bit?

Comment: @rama-vadakattu - Can you please mention the live URL & Screenshot of this problem. That can help in understanding the question better. 
Chrome dev-tools helps a lot in debugging this problem.