# Service Worker takes long to download content

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a service worker and am caching both css and js files.

While doing performance testing I noticed that the css and js files take a substantially longer time in the Content downloading stage with service worker enabled  as compared to my build with no service worker and content being served from disk cache.

Could anyone guide me on why this is happening?

To provide more info about the times

SW enabled    style.css - 15ms   main.js - 120ms
No SW          styles.css - 8ms  main.js - 75ms

Comment: Here is a similar question with no answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677586/service-worker-slow-response-times-for-css/51277979?noredirect=1#comment89533533_51277979  by https://stackoverflow.com/users/270442/rama-vadakattu for reference.

Comment: Please mention the live URL and few screenshots to understand this problem.